# AS3: Call to a possibly undefined method addEventListener through a reference with static type Class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am getting the following errors:

> Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 110, Column 14    1061: Call to a possibly undefined method addEventListener through a reference with static type Class.
>
> Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 113, Column 14 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method removeEventListener through a reference with static type Class.
>
> Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 128, Column 14 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method addEventListener through a reference with static type Class.
>
> Scene 1,
>   Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 131, Column 14 1061: Call to a possibly
>   undefined method removeEventListener through a reference with static
>   type Class.

the code part is:

```
    function allowTapCaveman():void {
/*line 110*/    btn_caveman.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, btn_cavemanMenu);
    }
    function cancelTapCaveman():void {
/*line 113*/    btn_caveman.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, btn_cavemanMenu);
    }
    function allowTapCavemanClose():void {
/*line 128*/    btn_caveman.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, btn_cavemanMenuClose);
    }
    function cancelTapCavemanClose():void {
/*line 138*/    btn_caveman.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, btn_cavemanMenuClose);
    }
```

btn_caveman is a movieclip (yeah I know I have 'btn') that gets called on the stage via an array;

```
var startingcaveman:Array = new Array();
for (var i:Number = 0; i<2; i++) {
    startingcaveman.push(new btn_caveman());
    addChild(startingcaveman[i]);
    startingcaveman[i].name = 'startingcavemen' +i;
    startingcaveman[i].x = Math.random()*550;
    startingcaveman[i].y = Math.random()*400;
}
    startingcaveman[0].x = 213.60;
    startingcaveman[0].y = 312.90;
    startingcaveman[1].x = 211.75;
    startingcaveman[1].y = 400.15;
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, example);
    function example (evt:Event) {
        for each (var btn_caveman in startingcaveman) {
            addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, btn_cavemanMenu3);
        }
    }
```

It's probably so simple but I can't get it which is annoying the hell outta me.

Comment: It means `btn_caveman` is the name of a class rather than an instance of a class.

Comment: @Marty Sorry maybe its because I have spent too long doing it but what on earth do I do to make it work?
Im doing this as a part of a group assessment for Uni and my group isnt helping me at all, all they are doing is playing games -.-

Comment: Either change the class name or the variable name to something different.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer which should allow you to fix your problem and in view of your coding style maybe get rid of many future problems as well:

You cannot use as a variable name the name of a class. In your case you have a class named btn_caveman but later on you try to use a variable named btn_caveman as well. Do not do that ever.

If you were to follow coding conventions you would never run into those type of problems. Class names should be that way:

```
ButtonCaveman
```

Variable name should be that way:

```
buttonCaveman
```

Answer (score 0):

This should to it

```
var startingcaveman:Array = [];
for (var i:Number = 0; i<2; i++) {
  // symbols should start with an upcase letter,
  // because they're classes
  // stick to "Caveman" for example
  var btn:MovieClip = new btn_caveman();
  startingcaveman.push(btn);
  addChild(btn);
  btn.name = 'startingcavemen' +i;
  btn.x = Math.random()*550;
  btn.y = Math.random()*400;
}

startingcaveman[0].x = 213.60;
startingcaveman[0].y = 312.90;
startingcaveman[1].x = 211.75;
startingcaveman[1].y = 400.15;
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, example);

function example (evt:Event) {
    // here was the error. you used the class name.
    // that's why naming is important!
    for each (var btn in startingcaveman) {
        btn.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, btn_cavemanMenu3);
    }
}
```

Comment: It got rid of the errors but then gave me this error:
`TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at stoneApp_new_fla::MainTimeline/allowTapCaveman()[stoneApp_new_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:115]
 at stoneApp_new_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()[stoneApp_new_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:22]
 at runtime::ContentPlayer/loadInitialContent()
 at runtime::ContentPlayer/playRawContent()
 at runtime::ContentPlayer/playContent()
 at runtime::AppRunner/run()
 at ADLAppEntry/run()
 at global/runtime::ADLEntry()
`

Comment: Line 115 is `btn.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, btn_cavemanMenu);`